# Ionic 3 Background Audio on IOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, background, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I'm looking for a way to play audio with the Ionic Media plugin. I have tried using Background mode https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/ , but it is not working for IOS, because in XCode I get

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

on the AppDelegate. I have added everything in the capabilities and the info.plist. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out the npm repo is not up to date, so for everyone struggling with this error it is a underscore in some file in the plugin "_requiredBack...", when it should be  "requiredBack...". Repo in git in updated, so you can fix this by just typing

> ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode --nofetch

or if you are not using Ionic, just cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode --nofetch .

Hope this helps!